# Trailing slash important, but stripped out?

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c

If I create a url a la:

```
const UInt8 *pFilepath = (const UInt8 *)[[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Documents/"] UTF8String];
CFURLRef ldestination = CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation (NULL, pFilepath, strlen((const char*)pFilepath), false);
```

and then log it to see what I've got a la:

```
NSLog(@"destination url:%@",(NSString*)ldestination);
```

the trailing slash on "/Documents/" is removed. Not a problem if it's not important. But when I do

```
dirPath = CFURLHasDirectoryPath(ldestination);
if (!dirPath) {
    fprintf(stderr, "no dice");
    return false;
}
```

the error is thrown. If instead, I pass an NSString which includes the trailing slash, it doesn't error on the CFURLHasDirectoryPath, but won't pass a

```
writeStream = CFWriteStreamCreateWithFile(kCFAllocatorDefault, ldestination);
assert(writeStream != NULL);
```

And idea what's going on? Ideally, I think that if I can keep the trailing slash on the CFURLRef, it'll pass the errors, but I don't know that for sure.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prototype of `CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation` is

```
CFURLRef CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation (
   CFAllocatorRef allocator,
   const UInt8 *buffer,
   CFIndex bufLen,
   Boolean isDirectory    // <------ note this
);
```

If you want a directory, pass `true` to the last parameter.

---

Also, use `-stringByAppendingPathComponent:` to append path components ("Documents") instead of `-stringByAppendingString:`. The former will deal with the slashes for you.

Use `-[NSFileManager fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory:]` to check whether a file is really a directory.